# Zero crossing solid state relays

Tags: solid-state-relay, inrush-current

For zero crossing relays, does the switching at zero current only limit voltage spikes, or does it also reduce inrush current?

Comment: Zero crossing SSR does not switch at zero current, rather at zero voltage. Possibly both of them, since it won't turn on an inductive load because of current VS. voltage lag. It does not limit the inrush current.

Comment: What are your assumptions and conclusions?  ZVS means On at 0 V and Triacs turn Off at 0A